# ajax wordpress getting 404 error unable to retrieve json from external website and print it on my datatable

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress, datatables

I having some issue when I try to access to external website via ajax.**404 error** will occur when I tried to access it thus unable to store the name parameter data and print on my datatable. 
This is one of the error prompt

> DataTables warning: table id=import - Ajax error.
>   For more information about this error. please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Below is my code please help thanks.

```
<?php echo datatable_scripts(); ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#import').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://example.com/hello.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataSrc: 'Data'
        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'name'}
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Below is my json output file from external website.

> {"data":[{"name":"_testing_product_009"},{"name":"_testing_product_010"},{"name":"_testing_product_008"},{"name":"_testing_product_007"},{"name":"_testing_product_006"},{"name":"_testing_product_005"},{"name":"_testing_product_004"},{"name":"_testing_product_003"},{"name":"_testing_product_002"},{"name":"testing
>   product lance"}]}

On my hello.php code

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");  //To enable cross-domain
include("../../../wp-blog-header.php");  //To enable wordpress core function


    $args = array( 
        'post_type'   => 'product', 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'nopaging'    => true
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); // $query is the WP_Query Object
    $posts = $query->get_posts();   // $posts contains the post objects

    $output = array();
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {  
        $output['data'][] = array( "name"=>$post->post_title );
    }

    echo json_encode($output); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
$("#import").DataTable({
  "ajax": "http://example.com/hello.php",
   columns: [
     {data: "name"}
   ]
});
```

I'm not sure if you need all the other options based on the format of your JSON. `dataSrc` is only needed if you are loading JSON that is in an incompatible format for DataTables.

Comment: Sorry but it not working. I am still having the same error.

Comment: @user1032181 If you open your Developer Tools in your browser, what do you get for errors in the console?